# Does Piwik and Sugar CRM uses the same framework?

Tags: sugarcrm, matomo, vtiger

I've been working with piwik, sugarcrm and vtiger.  I noticed their frameworks are very similar. vTiger is a derivative of sugarcrm, so that's understandable.   But Piwik and sugarcrm are also very similar.  Are they both built with the same framework?  If so, what is it called?

Answer (score 1):

vTiger is a fork of SugarCRM done back when Sugar was around version 4.5, and doesn't stay up to date with upstream Sugar releases.

While Pwick has some similarities in visual appearance to Sugar, they share no common code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Piwik, but SugarCRM and vTiger uses the Smarty Template engine.

http://www.smarty.net/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Piwik uses a subset of Zend framework

Comment: Short answers like these that don't fully answer the question should probably be placed in comments under the question.

Comment: That answer is actually the only one that is correct and answers the question. John asked for the framework these systems use - it's Zend. Both other answers failed to make that clear.